# How to restrict the html upload file type to *.xmind?

Tags: html, upload, mime, mindmap

Now I'm developing on an html page which wants to upload an XMind file (with extension name *.xmind).

I'm now making an `<input type="file" />` element to upload the file.

But the accept type cannot restrict to the file type `*.xmind`, is there any solutions?

---

#### My effort:

Using `accept="application/pdf"` attribute can restrict the file type to *.pdf.

I searched about the MIME type of *.xmind, seemed to be `application/x-xmind` (Ref: https://www.digipres.org/formats/mime-types/).

But using `accept="application/x-xmind"` attribute is not working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do this:

`<input type="file" accept=".xmind">`

Comment: Nice, I tried `accept="*.xmind"` but with no luck, your solution works! Thanks, you save my life!